# i18next - dynamically add gender when context is used

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I have the following:

```
t('translations::How are you?', { context: this.props.me.gender })
```

I'm currently using [i18next-scanner](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner) to auto generate a JSON namespace file. The problem I am having is when I use context, I get:

```
"How are you?": "How are you?"     // fallback
"How are you?_": "How are you?"    // context
```

What I'd really like to happen is whenever **context** is used in i18n, I'd like `male` and `female` to be generated like so:

```
"How are you?": "How are you?"
"How are you?_male": "How are you?"
"How are you?_female": "How are you?"
```

I haven't found a good way to dynamically add these keys. What things can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v reviewed the libs source code, from the tests, it looks like this lib is not supports this.

But, from [this code](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner/blob/0679261735133f5a07a9a4f6f9acb4d1f9b6bec4/src/parser.js#L912), if your `options.context` is a function, it will be invoked, that means that you will able to modify it.
Check this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-ptolemy-vd1xb

As you can see, I've managed to change the context type, but the lib is not supporting your case (base on [this line](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner/blob/0679261735133f5a07a9a4f6f9acb4d1f9b6bec4/src/parser.js#L949)) it adds only one context.

It can be a really simple PR :]

**Edit**
I've added this functionality to [i18next-scanner](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner#contextdefaultvalues), now you can specify `contextDefaultValues`- a list of values that will be used in a case of dynamic context values.

```
// i18next-scanner.config.js

module.exports = {
    input: [
        'app/**/*.{js,jsx}',
        // Use ! to filter out files or directories
        '!app/**/*.spec.{js,jsx}',
        '!app/i18n/**',
        '!**/node_modules/**',
    ],
    output: './',
    options: {
        ...
        contextDefaultValues: ['male', 'female'] // <--- specify this option  
        ...
    },
    ...
};
```

Comment: nice! Looks like it failed builds tho :'(

Comment: It is an issue with the repo, I've made a PR for the fix

Comment: It looks like the maintainers of this lib are not so active, if it is urgent for you, you can use my branch and create a patch with package-patch :]

Comment: I definitely think I will felix! Thank you!

Comment: The PR is merged :], https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner/pull/180#issuecomment-599322158

Comment: Niiiiice thanks for letting me know @felixmosh - you rock